# Exposing physical system memory and IO devices to docker container

Tags: docker, containers, hyper-v

I have been working on developing IOT solution for docker, and I found an help usage that docker does supports (pass-through for gpu, disks, usb and serial ports):

1. Exposing Nvidia GPU  device for computation
2. Exposing particular serial device etc. using flag `device`

So before just working around from scratch to implement the passthrough mechanism for system memory I wanted to know if there exist any way already exist to achieve the same or not to aid:

1. Read/Write physical system memory
2. Expose all IO devices in one shot!

Comment: As an isolation system, one of Docker's key design goals is to prohibit direct access to things like this.  Would it make more sense to run your process directly on the host?

Comment: If Hyper-V can passthrough the memory, it would avoid writing platform dependent drivers.